# Calling DLL in VB.Net using Pinvoke is giving PInvokeStackImbalance Exception (UCHAR*)

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, dll, pinvoke

I am trying to call a dll in VB.Net 2010 using PInvoke but I keep getting the PInvokeStackImbalance exception.

The signature of the function I am trying to call is:
MCBTTNEC_API DWORD Motion_TabletStatus1(UCHAR* TabletStatus1);

More information about the function can be found here:
http://support.motioncomputing.com/kb/KnowledgebaseArticle10943.aspx

I have tried the following but both give me PInvokeStackImbalance exception:

_
Private Function Motion_TabletStatus1(ByVal TabletStatus1 as IntPtr) as UInt32 
End Function

_
Private Function Motion_TabletStatus1(ByRef TabletStatus1 as Byte) as UInt32 
End Function

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks in advance.